# Sub that displays a line chart for a 2 entries table when a button is clicked

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently trying to create a sub (Excel VBA) that generates a form that displays a line chart for months and letters I want to freely select in a 2 entries table.

I want my sub to start when I click on a button that I already created (called Display Chart or Button1_Click).

Here is the code I came out with :

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    GenerateChart.Show
End Sub

Sub GenerateChart()

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim MyChart As Chart
    Dim DataRange As Range

    If ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet3" And Selection.Cells.Count > 0 Then

        Set DataRange = Selection
        Set MyChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
        MyChart.SetSourceData Source:=DataRange
        MyChart.ChartType = xlBarStacked

    End If

End Sub
```

For some reason, this does not seem to work. I think I did something wrong regarding the button click part. Indeed, I do not understand how this event is called (Display Chart or Button1_Click) and how to code it. Therefore I cannot check if my other lines of codes are correct.

I hope someone will be able to help me out, thanks a lot !

Comment: Do not use `On Error Resume Next` unless you apply it to make specific workarounds. You *need* to track your errors. Is it ActiveX button or FormsControl button?

Comment: I think it is a FormsControl button. I have tried to assign a macro (the GenerateChart Sub) to it but it still does not work.

Comment: Is a form actually involved or just a form control?

Comment: Because if just calling a sub it would be  GenerateChart without the .Show

Comment: Better to double check and see if *View code* is avaible when you click on your button.

Comment: Allright I've changed my code and deleted the first sub (Button1_Click), only to assign my second sub to my button. @QHarr, I do not understand your question, I think I have only created a form control.

Comment: then you don't need .Show and check the scope of any macros.

Comment: Oh it worked, thanks a lot ! So I added this `Sub Button1_Click() GenerateChart End Sub` without the .Show and it worked. Could you please explain me why I actually need to add this Sub ? I thought that only the "assignmacro" was needed (when you right click the button)

Answer (score 0):

Assign a Macro GenerateChart with the button and Select the data for which you need to create a Chart and click the button, I think you are not selected the data while you clicking the button here you used

```
Set DataRange = Selection
```

Comment: This is actually what I am doing and this is the wanted effect. Do you know why it does not work ?

Comment: Based on your data range only its creates a Chart and you have set DataRange as selection so you have to select content before executing Macro